# Work with vector (string) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I have array masiv_C0 = {{AB, ADF}, {BC, ADF}, {CD, BC}, {DE, ADF}}

I have array masiv_X0 = {{AB, ADF}, {CD, BC}, {DE, ADF}}

It is necessary to create a third array of the first two:

masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0 - masiv_X0 = {{BC, ADF}}

The problem is that in the third array which I create I delete individual elements.

As a result, rather than to obtain {{BC, ADF}} I get {{BC}} ... Help correct code! Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;
typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;

int main()
{
String2D masiv_C0(4, String1D(2));
masiv_C0[0][0]="AB";
masiv_C0[0][1]="ADF";
masiv_C0[1][0]="BC";
masiv_C0[1][1]="ADF";
masiv_C0[2][0]="CD";
masiv_C0[2][1]="BC";
masiv_C0[3][0]="DE";
masiv_C0[3][1]="ADF";

String2D masiv_X0(3, String1D(2));
masiv_X0[0][0]="AB";
masiv_X0[0][1]="ADF";
masiv_X0[0][0]="CD";
masiv_X0[0][1]="BC";
masiv_X0[0][0]="DE";
masiv_X0[0][1]="ADF";

String2D masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < masiv_X0.size(); ++i)
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < masiv_X0[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        auto& str = masiv_X0[i][j];
        for (size_t cur = 0; cur < masiv_Y1.size(); ++cur)
        {
            auto iter = std::remove(masiv_Y1[cur].begin(), masiv_Y1[cur].end(), str);
            masiv_Y1[cur].erase(iter, masiv_Y1[cur].end());
        }
    }
}

String2D::iterator iter = masiv_Y1.begin();
while (iter != masiv_Y1.end())
{
    std::copy((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, " "));
    cout << "\n";
    ++iter;
}

return 0; }
```

Comment: Note that C and C++ are different languages. I have corrected that for you. Please use only the relevant tags in the future.

Comment: The proper answer is fire up your development environment's debugger and step through the program until you see it deviate from the expected. Then using what you can see of the programs state, determine why it deviated. Recommendation: If the inputs are always pairs, don't use a `vector` of `vector`s, use a `vector` of `std::pair`s. Much faster due to improved locality and it is probably conceptually easier to move the pairs around without breaking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X-Y answer: Throw out what you are doing. The standard library does everything you need to do for you. No muss. No fuss.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // shorten this templated nightmare
    using vecpair = std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>;

    // define inputs
    vecpair masiv_C0{{"AB","ADF"},{"BC","ADF"},{"CD","BC"},{"DE","ADF"}};
    vecpair masiv_X0{{"AB","ADF"},{"CD","BC"},{"DE","ADF"}};

    // define output
    vecpair masiv_Y1;

    // use std library to do the work
    std::set_difference(masiv_C0.begin(), masiv_C0.end(),
                   masiv_X0.begin(), masiv_X0.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(masiv_Y1));

    // print it.
    for (const std::pair<std::string,std::string> & p: masiv_Y1)
    {
        std::cout << "{" << p.first << "," << p.second << "}\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Docs for `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

[Docs for `std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

[Docs for `std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Addendum note:

Everything above except the print loop should work with `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` as well should be `vector` of `vector` be an external, and performance-killing, requirement.